# How do I perform a wall-hang?

Tags: titanfall

One of the challenges in *Titanfall* is to kill X number of enemies while wall-hanging. I've seen plenty of other people hanging from a corner, but I can never seem to do it. I always either wall-*run*, or just fall off of the wall completely.

**Is there some trick to hanging motionless from the wall?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On PC, start moving like you're going to run up a wall and press the aim (default right mouse) button to wall hang. On Xbox, press down the left trigger. This [video should help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11E468qOLkg) as well.